# Pointer to character array output

Tags: c, pointers, character

When we declare a pointer to any integer say we declare it like

```
int i=5;
int *p=&i;
```

We use `*p` to get the value 5 and if we want the address we use `p` without asterisk sign to get the address. But in case of character array, when we say

```
char *str="HELLO";
```

We simply use `str` to get `"HELLO"` as output in printf function. Like this,

```
printf("%s",str);
```

Here we used `str` without asterisk.

Why aren't we getting an address and instead getting "HELLO" as output here while we get address in case of pointers to integers when we use the pointer variable without asterisk?

Comment: With `int *p=5;` You won't get the value `5` by `*p`. `p` is 5 and `*p` will probably lead to Segmentation Fault.

Comment: You are assigning the *address* 5 with `*p=5`.  You need `int i = 5; int *p = &i`.  *Then* `*p` references 5 and `p` references the address.

Comment: In `printf`, `%s` *expects* an address, and `printf` is coded to print the characters at that address up to a null character.

Comment: Why does printf("%d",p) show address as output in case of integers while it prints characters in case of string and not address ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay first of all `int *p=5;` is wrong! you cant do that in the declaration of a pointer. at That time the pointer expects an adress. You should do `int *p;` and then `*p = 5;` to assign the value to it.

```
printf("%s",str); // prints the value of the variable, because its a pointer.
printf("%s",*str); // the * will cause to a segmentation fault

int *p // the * there is just used to tell the compiler that you are declaring a pointer of type integer.

/* another scope after declaring your pointer */

*p //is used to get value of a pointer variable.(dereference it)
&p //is used to get the adress of a pointer variable.
p //contains an adress.
```

Comment: printf("%s",str) doesn't print address rather it prints value.